# jQuery; Trace the height of an element which is animating via slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm animating an element in jQuery and I need the also animate the `margin` of another element to follow the `height` of the animating element while it slides down.

So for example, the `slideDown()` function starts on **element x**, and somehow the `animate` function of the corresponding element knows **element x**'s height ***as it slides*** down and copies it, animating in unison.

Hopefully I've explained it well, let me know if you want more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) property:

```
$("#first").animate({ /* properties */ }, {
    step : function() {
        var height = $(this).height();
        $("#second").css("margin-top", height);
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use this with the `slideDown` function?